# How to get data and make condition from 2 models in controller react js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, controller

I create login form with reactjs app and also i create api. For backend i want to create function that only role admin can logged in inside coz for now every user can login to backend.
i have function for login, this is my api function:

```
const login = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { body } = req;
    const { username, password } = body;

    ...

    } else {
        UserModel.find({
            username: username
        }, (err, users) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Error: Server error.'
                })
            } else if (users.length != 1) {
                res.send({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Error: User not exist!'
                })
            } else {
                const user = users[0]
                const roleId = user.role

                const role = await checkUserRole(roleId)
                console.log(role)

                if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                    res.send({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'Error: Password not match.'
                    })
                } else {
                    res.send({
                        success: true,
                        message: 'Login success'
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and i want to check if role user is admin, so i create function before

```
const checkUserRole = async (roleId) => {
    return RoleModel.findById(roleId).exec((err, role) => {
        if (err) {
            return message = 'Server error.'
        } else if (role.roleName != 'admin') {
            return message = 'You are not admin. Please use admin credential!'
        }
    })
}
```

but the result when i `console.log(role)` is `undefined`.

How to get result from `checkUserRole`? Or did i missed something?

Comment: add `return` before this `RoleModel.findById.....`

Comment: still undefined

Comment: `checkUserRole` is an asynchronous function. Your pointer move to the next statement after executing the `checkUserRole` withoug waiting for the response from that.

Comment: i've made changes to const checkUserRole = async (roleId) => ... and in function login const role = await checkUserRole(roleId) but still error with message: await is only valid in async function

Comment: i update code above

Comment: You also need to make the login function as async

Comment: also same, i tried before. the error is still same at const role = await checkUserRole(roleId)

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work:

```
const checkUserRole = async (roleId) => {
    return await RoleModel.findById(roleId,(err, role) => {
        if (err) {
            return message = 'Server error.'
        } else if (role.roleName != 'admin') {
            return message = 'You are not admin. Please use admin credential!'
        }
    })
}
```

Your original code is not working because you are wrapping the promise returned by exec into the callback. The above code returns the query. You can also try another option using only `exec()` without the callback and handle the errors with a `try catch`.